# Inner join and Like Clause in sql

Tags: sql

I want to search using Like in my inner join statement.

Search:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM CARS 
 WHERE (plate_no LIKE '%$search%' OR eng_no LIKE '%$search%' 
        or chass_no like '%$search%' or car_year  LIKE '%$search%' 
        or car_brand LIKE '%$search%' or car_model LIKE '%La%' 
        or horse_power LIKE '%$search%') 
   AND status='sold'
```

Inner join:

```
  SELECT cars.
     plate_no, cars.car_condition, cars.photo_path, cars.car_year, 
     cars.car_brand, cars.car_model, transaction.actual_price, customer_maintenance.id
  FROM 
     `cars` 
  INNER JOIN 
     transaction ON (cars.id = transaction.car_id)
  INNER JOIN 
     customer_maintenance ON (transaction.customer_id = customer_maintenance.id) 
  WHERE
     status = 'sold'
```

Comment: Copy your WHERE from 1 query to the second.Add the table alias where is needed.

Comment: What database platform are you using?  There are some RDBMS features and built-in operators that are database specific that could further help you with this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
SELECT cars.plate_no, 
       cars.car_condition, 
       cars.photo_path, 
       cars.car_year, 
       cars.car_brand, 
       cars.car_model, 
       transaction.actual_price, 
       customer_maintenance.id 
FROM   cars 
       INNER JOIN transaction 
               ON transaction.car_id = cars.id 
       INNER JOIN customer_maintenance 
               ON transaction.customer_id = customer_maintenance.id 
WHERE  cars.status = 'sold' 
       AND ( cars.plate_no LIKE '%$search%' 
              OR cars.eng_no LIKE '%$search%' 
              OR cars.chass_no LIKE '%$search%' 
              OR cars.car_year LIKE '%$search%' 
              OR cars.car_brand LIKE '%$search%' 
              OR cars.car_model LIKE '%La%' 
              OR cars.horse_power LIKE '%$search%' )
```

Answer (score 0):

What is also valid is to extend the match expression of the INNER JOIN clause by just replacing it with a more complex expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM   cars 
   INNER JOIN transaction 
           ON transaction.car_id = cars.id AND car.brand like '%search%'
   INNER JOIN customer_maintenance 
           ON transaction.customer_id = customer_maintenance.id 
WHERE  cars.status = 'sold'
```

Putting this in the WHERE clause leads to the same result.